# Is it possible for firebase to update itself?

Tags: json, firebase

I need to provide every user with data from different sites. Each of the site provides data in JSON format, but some of them have restriction to maximal number of request.

My idea for solution is to download the data to firebase periodically, than users will access just the firebase database.
From docs it seems to me that firebase can somehow use http requests.

Can I use firebase to periodically update itself by http request?
Or should I establish server which will do the task?

I am pretty new to those topics so any tip where to look for information will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's possible. High level overview... The idea would be to use a 3rd-party chron job service to trigger cloud function... said cloud function make ajax request to get new website data... said cloud function then uses the Firebase admin sdk to update the database with the data it received.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Those are the information I had hard time to find.